# Appearing element disappears after animation

Tags: css-animations, visibility, keyframe

I need some help with the visibility property. I'm trying to make an element appear and once it has appeared **keeps being visible**.  That's this last point that I'm trying to get. I made it appear, but disappears right after the animation.

I suspect the element to take back its hidden value right after the animation ends and I don't know how to make its new visible value stable.

Thanks guys!

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: appearing-menu 0.8s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes appearing-menu {
  from {
    visibility: visible;
    bottom: -50px;
    opacity: 0;
    }
  to {
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<h1>The @keyframes Rule</h1>

<div></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `animation: appearing-menu 0.8s forwards;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

> forwards
>
> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe
> encountered during execution.

and added the `visibility: visible` to the last frame.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: appearing-menu 0.8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes appearing-menu {
  from {
    visibility: visible;
    bottom: -50px;
    opacity: 0;
    }
  to {  
    visibility: visible;
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;     
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1>The @keyframes Rule</h1>

<div></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate, it works wonderfully. So the "forwards" made the difference, I suppose. I'll look into that.

Comment: yes.. from the mdn link I shared in the answer: `forwards - The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution.` ... Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Stack Overflow and didn't know that I had to accept answers. I'll do that for my other posts as well.